# Wordpress File Download: Contact Form 7

Tags: wordpress

At the bottom right this wordpress page, I have a contact form 7 which says "How to date in the marriage zone".

https://soulconnectcoaching.com/

I know the plugins contact form 7 and Popup Maker are used, but could not find out how to change the file that is downloaded from filling out that form. **Does anyone know how to change the file downloaded from the contact form in either the Popup Maker plugin or Contact Form plugin (I don't know which)?**

Here's where i think the setting can be changed, but i can't find it. The file is downloaded directly after the form is submitted (the file is not emailed afterwords)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a java script code which is used for file:

```
<script>
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
if ( '123' == event.detail.contactFormId ) {
    location = 'https://soulconnectcoaching.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/how-to-date-in-the-marriage-zone.pdf';
}}, false );
</script>
```

so find the code either in home page template or footer and just replace the pdf file name .

Comment: I updated the file, thanks! I actually had to log into godaddy to upload the file manually under wp-content/.../..., is there a more user-friendly way to do it like from within the wordpress dashboard?

Comment: yes you can do this by adding a field in dashboard for file upload , you can use a advanced custom field plugin for creating a file upload field in wp dashboard  , but you will also needed to add some php code in template to get file , if you need help i can assist you to add such functionality.